# How to authorize proxy with BrowserMobProxyServer?

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I need to use the remote proxy server for my test, but proxy required login and password for authorization. I try to use `BrowserMobProxyServer` for this:

```
BrowserMobProxy bmp = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
bmp.start();
// This inject my remote proxy ip:port and login password.
bmp.autoAuthorization("111.111.111.111:8000", "l0gVal", "pasVal", AuthType.BASIC);

Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(bmp);
// I guess if info about this proxy already injected it should work without loin & password form but auth alert whenever appear( 
proxy.setHttpProxy("111.111.111.111:8000");
proxy.setSslProxy("111.111.111.111:8000");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://whoer.net");
```

Help me understand my mistake, I sure it's possible, but how.
I get this exception:

> tarting ChromeDriver 2.35.528157
>   (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef) on port 30000 Only local
>   connections are allowed. 2018-04-26 11:45:22 ERROR
>   o.l.p.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (AWAITING_INITIAL) at
>   net.lightbody.bmp.util.BrowserMobHttpUtil.removeMatchingPort(BrowserMobHttpUtil.java:274)
>   ~[browsermob-core-2.1.0-beta-6.jar:na]    at
>   net.lightbody.bmp.filters.HttpsHostCaptureFilter.clientToProxyRequest(HttpsHostCaptureFilter.java:36)
>   ~[browsermob-core-littleproxy-2.1.0-beta-6.jar:na]    at
>   net.lightbody.bmp.filters.BrowserMobHttpFilterChain.clientToProxyRequest(BrowserMobHttpFilterChain.java:65)
>   ~[browsermob-core-littleproxy-2.1.0-beta-6.jar:na]    at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.doReadHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:227)
>   ~[littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]   at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.readHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:191)
>   ~[littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]   at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.readHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:80)
>   ~[littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]   at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.readHTTP(ProxyConnection.java:135)
>   ~[littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]   at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.read(ProxyConnection.java:120)
>   ~[littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]   at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.channelRead0(ProxyConnection.java:587)
>   ~[littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]   at
>   io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection$RequestReadMonitor.channelRead(ProxyConnection.java:715)
>   [littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:277)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:264)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection$BytesReadMonitor.channelRead(ProxyConnection.java:692)
>   [littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-12.jar:na]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:962)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
>   [netty-all-4.0.36.Final.jar:4.0.36.Final]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101] Apr 26, 2018
>   11:45:23 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Answer (score 1):

"on port 30000 Only local connections are allowed"

seems to me that the proxy is refusing connection

check the proxy configuation or use another port

Comment: but port I got from the proxy provider. 111.111.111.111:`8000` I can't specify this parameter. Or you mean something else?

Comment: "on port 30000" means, that comunication try go through port 30000. Maybe you can't event reach the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is using custum browser profile; similar as described in [Automatically download pdf in firefox gecko driver using selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276253/automatically-download-pdf-in-firefox-gecko-driver-using-selenium-java/50294608#50294608). Didn't tried Chrome yet. At least you can exclude cause in your code.