# Automatically download pdf in firefox gecko driver using selenium java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Can anyone help to create a profile and set options using firefox (**gecko** **driver**) to automatically download files in selenium webdriver - java. I have already searched a lot of options googling around, and nothing much worked. So posting my query on stack overflow. Please help with some code snippet if possible. This is for selenium 3 and firefox version 52.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309314/set-firefox-profile-to-download-files-automatically-using-selenium-and-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Anton : Had seen this one earlier. It did not work :)

Answer (score 0):

1/ create a new firefox profile manualy in firefox.exe -p

2/ run firefox with this new profile and set up to automaticly download PDF files

3/ use this:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
        FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("NAME OF THE NEW FIREFOX PROFILE");
        options.setProfile(selenium_profile);

        options.setBinary("PATH TO FIREFOX.EXE");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH TO GECKODRIVER.EXE");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
```

using existing custom firefox profile, you can run your test with almost any firefox setting modification (proxy setings, 1 imported certificate with no asking, extensions, etc.)

No more need to specify in code:

```
FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        selenium_profile.setPreference...
```